# error: ‘str’ undeclared (first use in this function) b = bst_inorder(b->left, str);

Tags: c, recursion, binary-search-tree

Here is my code. I keep getting an error

```
bst.c:30:30: error: ‘str’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

> ```
> b = bst_inorder(b->left, str);
> ```

Which I am unsure of as it has definitely already been declared?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "bst.h"
#include "mylib.h"


struct bstnode {
    char *key;
    bst left;
    bst right;
};

extern bst bst_delete(bst b, char *str);
extern bst bst_free(bst b){
    free (b->key);
    free(b);
    return b;

}

void print_key(char *s){
    print("%\n", s);
}

extern void bst_inorder(bst b, void f(char *str)){
    if (b == NULL){
        return;
    }
    b = bst_inorder(b->left, str);
    print_key(str);
    b = bst_inorder(b->right, str);            
}

extern bst bst_insert(bst b, char *str){
    if (b == NULL){
        b= emalloc(sizeof *b);
        b->key = emalloc((strlen(str)+1) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(b->key, str);
        return b;
    }
    else if (strcmp(str,b->key) == 0){
        return b;
    }
    else if (strcmp(str,b->key) < 0){
        b->left = bst_insert(b->left,str);
         return b->left;
    }
    else if (strcmp(str, b->key) > 0){
        b->right = bst_insert(b->right, str);
        return b->right;
    }
    return b;
}

extern bst bst_new(){
    return NULL;
}
extern void bst_preorder(bst b, void f(char *str)){
    if (b == NULL){}
}
extern int bst_search(bst b, char *str){
    if (b == NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    else if(strcmp(str,b->key) == 0){
        return 1;
        }
    else if(strcmp(str,b->key) < 0) {
        bst_search(b->left, str);
    }
    else if(strcmp(str,b->key) > 0){
        bst_search(b->right, str);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not declared at that point. Perhaps you're mistaken by the declaration of `f(char *str)` *inside* the definition of `bst_inorder`?

Comment: extern void bst_inorder(bst b, void f(char *str)) , is that a typo ?

Answer (score 2):

`bst_inorder` does not take a `char*` named "str", but a function named "f".

The name "str" is not declared - it's only there as a hint to the human reader and is ignored by the compiler.

The prototype is equivalent to

```
void bst_inorder(bst b, void f(char *))
```

You're supposed to apply the function to each string in the tree:

```
extern void bst_inorder(bst b, void f(char *)){
    if (b == NULL){
        return;
    }
    bst_inorder(b->left, f);
    f(b->key);
    bst_inorder(b->right, f);            
}
```

This makes it a generic traversal function - it lets the caller decide what to do with each node without having to write their own traversal code.

Examples:

```
void print(char *str) { printf("%s\n", str); }
int length = 0;
void count(char *str) { length += strlen(str); }

bst tree = ...
bst_inorder(tree, print); /* Prints the nodes in alphabetical order */
bst_inorder(tree, count);
printf("The tree's total character count is %d\n", length);
```